# How to replace inner html of one <div> to another </div> through jquery

Tags: jquery

I have two div tags: one contain an `img` tag inside and the other contain something else.

My first `<div>` contains an image. When I click on that image, or on some `<div>` having id `insideFrameimg`, it should show the second `<div id="insideFrameobj" style="display:none;">` in place of `<div id="insideFrameimg">`.

```
<div id="insideFrameimg"><!-- first div-->
  <img src="my-image.png"/>
<div>

<div id="insideFrameobj"> <!--second div -->
  hello this is my description
</div>
```

I want to show the complete inner html of `<div id="insideFrameobj">` in place of the first `<div>` when I click on `<img>` found inside the `<div id="insideFrameimg">` using jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

```
<div id="insideFrameimg"><!-- first div-->
  <img id="imgClick" src=""/>
  <div>

  <div id="insideFrameobj"> <!--second div -->
       hello this is my description>
   </div>
```

Something like this should help. It will replace first div content with second div content.

```
$('#imgClick').click(function () {
 $('#insideFrameimg').html($('#insideFrameobj').html());

});
```

Comment: hey my insideFrameobj div style is none.when i click it should be display

Comment: I have used you all given code but bcoz my insideFrameobj div is hide then how your code will work

Comment: If you want to just show your second div, try the following code: $('#imgClick').click(function () {
 $('#insideFrameobj').show();

});

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`children`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) function to get all children of `insideFrameobj` and use the [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) function to move them to `insideFrameimg`. That would typically be better than using `innerHTML` (or its jQuery wrapper `html`) because you're not tearing down the elements and recreating them (which would lose their event handlers). It's also more efficient.

That would look something like this:

```
$("#insideFrameimg").click(function() {
    $(this).append($("#insideFrameobj").children());
});
```

Naturally this leaves `insideFrameobj` empty, which seems to be what you want. If you don't, you might [`clone`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) the children and append the clones:

```
$("#insideFrameimg").click(function() {
    $(this).append($("#insideFrameobj").children().clone());
//                           difference is here ---^
});
```

But if any of the children have `id` values, cloning them and adding the clones will result in an invalid document, since `id`s **must** be unique. (This is not just a theoretical issue; it *will* cause trouble for your page, if you ever use those IDs.)

Comment: +1! Much better than `.innerHTML` or jQuery's `.html()`. Besides the fact that you would loose bound events, memory leaks could occur when they are deleted like that. IE has problems with that.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the contents of the `div` when the `img` is clicked:

```
$('#insideFrameimg img').click(function() {
    var contents = $('#insideFrameobj').html();
    $('#insideFrameimg').html(contents);
});
```